# Sencha Touch: XTemplate not visible in DataView

Tags: templates, touch, extjs, dataview

I'm a newbie to all the Sencha Touch stuff, but until now I'm very enthousiastic about it's capabilities. There is one problem, i somehow can't solve.

I would like to use a Tpl (XTemplate) for a calender view. The idea is to create a div element for every appointment, which i can place within  containers to layout them. Somehow i can't get the dataview to work.

I've stripped down my code to the bare minimum: a panel containing a DataView. When i use the itemTpl, everything works fine. But when I use the tpl (with or without the XTemplate) i don't see anything. I checked if it was just a display malfunction (searched for the XXX from the template), but that's not the case.

This is my code:

```
Ext.define('InfoApp.view.CalendarDay', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'calendarday',
requires: [ 'InfoApp.store.sAppointments'],
config: {
    title: 'Dag',
    layout: 'fit',
        items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'dataview',
                    store: 'appointmentStore',

                    //itemTpl: [ 'XXX {day} {course}' ] --> Works
                    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">XXX {day} {course}</tpl>')--> Doesn't Work... 
                }        
        ]
}
});
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or improvements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks @brink for your answer.

It took me a couple of days, but this worked for me:

```
  // Load the store
  var store = Ext.getStore('appointmentStore');

  // Get the current range of the store
  var data = store.getRange();

  // Create a custom template
  var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(<tpl for=".">{day} {course}</tpl>);

  // Loop through the data array 
  var showData = array(); 
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      showData.push(data[i].data); 
  }

  // Get the panel by ID and push the html template
  var panel = Ext.getCmp('appointmentspanel');
  panel.updateHtml(tpl.applyTemplate(showData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ST2 and not ST1

From http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-tpl and the comments on the tpl: config in the docs, it appears there's a bug when using a remote store. Even if your store has data it. tpl: apparently only works right now if your data is hardcoded in data:[]

you can use itemTpl: new XTemplate(), or itemTpl: XTemplate.from('someid') or you can defer specifying until afterwards, grab your dataview and go dv.setItemTpl(new XTemplate()), etc.